# Inactivity, disconnecting from the service - using Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used firebase database in my application. The application is running when I run the application in the emulator. But when I run it again in emulate, I get this error "Inactivity, disconnecting from the service". The application is not opening at the splash screen waiting. why could it be. I looked at similar problems, but I did not get a clear answer.
Thank you.

D/FA: Connected to remote service

V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4

V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: The "FA" in the log messages stands for Firebase Analytics.  These are informational messages and are not an indication of an error.  If your app is not starting properly, the cause is something else.

Comment: The problem is related to activity start. This answer changed my viewpoint. thank you so much.

Comment: can you please elaborate your understanding? As I am also stuck in the same thing. Activity start takes a lot of time. I have put my firebase call in onStart method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1 followed by V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713528/v-fa-processing-queued-up-service-tasks-1-followed-by-v-fa-inactivity-discon)

Answer (score 0):

This problem mainly happens due to a value being :none: or empty inside firebase, you should add a certain condition being it an if clause so that you dont have to retrieve an empty value.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What conditions for example should we add?