# V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, logcat

I face this problem in two android projects . In one i was trying to retrieve data from Firebase into Recyclerview and in onother i was trying to login using phone number but in both cases logcat is showing V/FA:

```
 Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: The "FA" in the log messages stands for Firebase Analytics. These are informational messages and are not an indication of an error.  If you are experiencing problems in your apps, they are caused by something else.

Comment: Every project connected to firebase showing same message in logcat

Comment: @BobSnyder now how to solve this issue?

Comment: There is nothing to fix.  There is no problem.  When Firebase Analytics has not events to report, it disconnects from the reporting service.  It reconnects later when it has events to report.  Ignore the message.

Comment: @bobsynder sir actually i am developing currently two apps where in both the projects i am retrieving data from firebase database into recyclerview but app shows blank screen and gets crashed and in the logcat i get the message inactivity disconnecting from the service.

Comment: The crashes you are experiencing are caused by something else.  You should post another question showing the stack trace for the crash.

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713528/v-fa-processing-queued-up-service-tasks-1-followed-by-v-fa-inactivity-discon

Comment: Just by restarting simulator solved this issue for me, It happens when simulator switch network connection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> `Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`

You Need to follow few steps to remove this problem.
`Reason: You face this problem because in the background there are few-thread and the process is running in the android studio which uses the connection of firebase and your process not get the connection.`

Steps:

1. Uninstall the app from your mobile/emulator.
2. Then go to the File option in the main menubar in the android studio.
3. Then click on Invalidatecasha/restart.

It takes few mints and restarts you android studio and that error is gone.
Because all the backend thread and process are closed.

Happy Coding.

Comment: this didn't help !

Comment: it didn't work for me too.

Comment: It didn't work for me too... I also lost my local history

Comment: it mean your problem is generated by another cause not due to the background thread , so re-check the all listener's in your app careful. if you use one listener depend into another listener then just try to make it independent

Comment: check my answer guys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713528/v-fa-processing-queued-up-service-tasks-1-followed-by-v-fa-inactivity-discon

Comment: seems NOT working

Comment: @Ben this error is generated due to a lot of reasons and there are a lot of possible solutions according to the problem occur. It is one of the possible solution, which occur due to the backend thread.

Comment: Hello everyone, frankly speaking you guys don't need to make any changes in code. follow these steps and after some time try connecting firebase through app it will work for sure.... i tried code changes which didnt worked and again i revert back to original after that followed these steps again and got worked...its because of firebase thread running in android studio....

Comment: Hello everyone, frankly speaking you guys don't need to make any changes in code. follow these steps and after some time try connecting firebase through app it will work for sure.... i tried code changes which didnt worked and again i revert back to original after that followed these steps again and got worked...its because of firebase thread running in android studio....

Comment: NOT working at all.

Comment: I even tried restarting the computer and it does not work for me.

Comment: This broke down my code!!! Do not try this solution.

Comment: This worked for me only the first time. After that issue is still there :(

Comment: I have even tried "./gradlew uninstallAll". But It didn't help

Comment: This worked for me :) Thanks!

Comment: I am using Flutter. It worked for me. I faced this problem after coming back to manual installation after trying to swtich to the FlutterFire CLI (they didn't say it didn't work for Analytics on Android at the time...). I had to re-use the google-serivces.json etc. Probably a cache problem.

Comment: This is not a solution. This is just an temporary solution for development.