# V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service after successfully generating .apk

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-studio-3.0, disconnect

I have been compiling my Android app without problems for months. I am using `Android Studio 3.4.1`. I still can run the app. The problem is that after a few seconds (not even a minute for sure), I see this:

```
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

The app is executing but it does not report actions to Android Studio anymore. I see this:

[image]

But in the Android Studio logs, it seems as if the app was already stopped. No reports at all about what I am doing on the app. I can still stop the app if I press the stop button, and it responds to that though. But other than being able to stop the app, nothing is reported in the Android Studio logs.

I already tried the solution provided by Sohaib Aslam at [V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080700/v-fa-inactivity-disconnecting-from-the-service). It does not fix the problem for me. I tried restarting the computer, using `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...`, connecting a physical phone to the laptop instead of running it from the Android Studio Emulator, and the result is always the same:

```
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

I cannot tell why this started to happen. I had been compiling my app correctly. The last thing I remember that I did was to use `Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK...`. The `.apk` file was generated correctly. But then I found a bug and tried to debug the app again by using `System.out.println()` and `Log.d()`. The problem about `V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service` started to happen. I do not see how generating an `.apk` file could cause this problem. I have not found solutions online to this issue. Any ideas? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

Some context of what happens before I see the line about disconnection for inactivity:

```
I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event listener
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe773e460: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcae782d0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe773e460: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcae782d0)
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Maybe this line about `Removing display event listener` is a good hint about what is causing the problem?

Comment: Those two are not related. Try Restarting your phone

Comment: @SaranSankaran I already tried restarting the phone from the Android Studio Emulator, including uninstalling the app. I still see `V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird. My workaround was to test changes by displaying values of variables on elements of the graphical user interface.

Comment: Hi @jaime can you tell me the detail of your provided solution?