# loop throw nodes of child from firebase database and storage into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to Retrieve data from Firebase database and storage into a RecyclerView and CardView , i don't get any error on the code but when i run the application nothing shows up and i get a message in the run like this (V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c2f66cf time:168073912
)
i have tried many solutions like this one here [V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080700/v-fa-inactivity-disconnecting-from-the-service)
but it didn't workout with me

my photo folder in firebase database name /doctor_images

this is my class Doctor

```
public class Doctor {
private String doctor_ID;
private String doctor_Name;
private String doctor_Email;
private String doctor_Phone;
private String doctor_Speciality;
private int doctor_Rating;
private String doctor_Image_Url;
public String getDoctor_ID() {
    return doctor_ID;
}
public void setDoctor_ID(String doctor_ID) {
    this.doctor_ID = doctor_ID;
}
public String getDoctor_Name() {
    return doctor_Name;
}
public void setDoctor_Name(String doctor_Name) {
    this.doctor_Name = doctor_Name;
}
public String getDoctor_Email() {
    return doctor_Email;
}
public void setDoctor_Email(String doctor_Email) {
    this.doctor_Email = doctor_Email;
}
public String getDoctor_Phone() {
    return doctor_Phone;
}
public void setDoctor_Phone(String doctor_Phone) {
    this.doctor_Phone = doctor_Phone;
}
public String getDoctor_Speciality() {
    return doctor_Speciality;
}
public void setDoctor_Speciality(String doctor_Speciality) {
    this.doctor_Speciality = doctor_Speciality; }
public int getDoctor_Rating() {
    return doctor_Rating;
}
public void setDoctor_Rating(int doctor_Rating) {
    this.doctor_Rating = doctor_Rating;
}
public String getDoctor_Image_Url() {
    return doctor_Image_Url;
}
public void setDoctor_Image_Url(String doctor_Image_Url) {
    this.doctor_Image_Url = doctor_Image_Url; }
public Doctor() { }
public Doctor(String doctor_ID, String doctor_Name, String doctor_Email, 
String doctor_Phone, String doctor_Speciality, int doctor_Rating, String 
doctor_Image_Url) {
    this.doctor_ID = doctor_ID;
    this.doctor_Name = doctor_Name;
    this.doctor_Email = doctor_Email;
    this.doctor_Phone = doctor_Phone;
    this.doctor_Speciality = doctor_Speciality;
    this.doctor_Rating = doctor_Rating;
    this.doctor_Image_Url = doctor_Image_Url; }}
```

and my Adapter code is this

```
public class DoctorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorAdapter.DoctorViewHolder> {
private Context mcontext;
private List<Doctor> mDoctor;
public DoctorAdapter (Context context , List<Doctor> doctors){
    mcontext = context;
    mDoctor = doctors; }
@NonNull
@Override
public DoctorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.image_doctor,parent,false);
    return new DoctorViewHolder(v); }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DoctorViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Doctor doctorCurrent = mDoctor.get(position);
    holder.txtNameDoctor.setText(doctorCurrent.getDoctor_Name());
    holder.txtSpecialityDoctor.setText(doctorCurrent.getDoctor_Speciality());
    Picasso.with(mcontext)
            .load(doctorCurrent.getDoctor_Image_Url())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imgDoctor); }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDoctor.size(); }
public class DoctorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView txtNameDoctor;
    public TextView txtSpecialityDoctor;
    public ImageView imgDoctor;
    public DoctorViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtNameDoctor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doctor_name_recycler_card);
        txtSpecialityDoctor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doctor_Speciality_recycler_card);
        imgDoctor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doctor_image_recycler_card); }
}
```

}

and my card Layout

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_all_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_shape"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/doctor_image_recycler_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/container_text_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/doctor_name_recycler_card"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/doctor_Speciality_recycler_card"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my RecyclerView in my Layout

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle_search_doctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and this is my Activity java class

```
public class AllDoctorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView ;
private DatabaseReference mdatabaseReference;
private DoctorAdapter mdoctorAdapter;
private List<Doctor> mdoctors;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_doctor);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_search_doctor);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mdoctors = new ArrayList<>();
    mdatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doctors");
    mdatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Doctor doctor = postSnapShot.getValue(Doctor.class);
                mdoctors.add(doctor);
            }
            mdoctorAdapter = new DoctorAdapter(AllDoctorActivity.this,mdoctors);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mdoctorAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AllDoctorActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

this is my doctor json code
i have added 2 doctors in 1 hospital and 1 doctor in another hospital

```
"doctors" : {
"-MEOD5GJqtMUR6V4XGbO" : {
  "-MGmxz1j6vmSzK0DlExJ" : {
    "doctor_Email" : "576",
    "doctor_Image_Url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-appointment",
    "doctor_Name" : "yyyy",
    "doctor_Phone" : "756",
    "doctor_Rating" : "3",
    "doctor_Speciality" : "756"
  },
  "-MGmy0tSdXTq4X0Nhqpb" : {
    "doctor_Email" : "576",
    "doctor_Image_Url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-appointment",
    "doctor_Name" : "yyyy",
    "doctor_Phone" : "756",
    "doctor_Rating" : "3",
    "doctor_Speciality" : "756"
  }
},
"-MGN5Lno-SA7b50ACOpK" : {
  "-MGwJr8Z1GmVdNrYcMyA" : {
    "doctor_Email" : "abdo53@gmail.com",
    "doctor_Image_Url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-appointment",
    "doctor_Name" : "محمد",
    "doctor_Phone" : "56777747",
    "doctor_Rating" : "1",
    "doctor_Speciality" : "56777747"
  }
}
```

},

and this is my hospital json code

```
  "hospitals" : {
"-MEOD5GJqtMUR6V4XGbO" : {
  "hospital_address" : "شارع بغداد",
  "hospital_name" : "عبد القادر المتوكل",
  "hospital_number" : "777777",
  "hospital_phone" : "7777777",
  "id" : "-MEOD5GJqtMUR6V4XGbO"
},
"-MGN5Lno-SA7b50ACOpK" : {
  "hospital_address" : "شارع الزبيري",
  "hospital_name" : "الجمهوري",
  "hospital_number" : "555555",
  "hospital_phone" : "77555555",
  "id" : "-MGN5Lno-SA7b50ACOpK"
},
"-MGOHrjqhGZ8EjeGHPjW" : {
  "hospital_address" : "الستين",
  "hospital_name" : "ازال",
  "hospital_number" : "88888",
  "hospital_phone" : "888888",
  "id" : "-MGOHrjqhGZ8EjeGHPjW"
}
```

}

Comment: Check read & write rules are set to true, inside rules tab. incase during configuration of firebase you missed it.

Comment: i have checked and they are all true @Vaibhav_sorathiya